# OBLLoader + MTLLoader Model not showing after adding material

Tags: javascript, three.js

For whatever reason when I apply a material loaded with MTLLoader to my model loaded with OBJLoader, the model itself disappears.

```
MTLLoader.setPath( 'models/' );
var url = "model.mtl";
MTLLoader.load( url, function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();
    OBJLoader.setPath( 'models/' );
    OBJLoader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {

object.traverse(function(child) {
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          child.material = materials ; // this is the problem
      }
        scene.add( object );
    });
  });
```

I know the way to set materials with MTLLoader is with `OBJLoader.setMaterials(materials)` but I would like to to do it the way I have above. But doing it this method makes the object vanish for whatever reason without any errors. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`child.material` expects some kind of material, e.g. MeshPhongMaterial. But `materials` given by the callback function of `MTLLoader.load` is not that kind of material. Looking into the source code reveals that the callback gives you a `MaterialCreator` object. This object contains a `materials` map, where all materials parsed from the mtl file are listed by name. So, to assign the material to your object, you can write:

```
child.material = materials.materials[ materialName ];
```

Alternatively, if there is only one material and you don't know the material name, you could also do:

```
child.material = materials.getAsArray()[0];
```

Or have a look at the object itself: `console.log(materials)`.

*Disclaimer: I have just looked up the source code of MTLLoader, I haven't tested it.*

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to use `materialName` externally?

Comment: You could iterate over the properties: `for (var materialName in materials.materials) { child.material = materials.material[ materialName ]; }` Of course, this doesn't make too much sense, if there are multiple materials in the mtl file. It would be much easier with `objloader.setMaterials()`. I don't know, why you don't want to use it?

Comment: I think I've done something wrong because `setMaterials()` end up overriding if I have more than one function.